# Hide the rightNavigationBar button item in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigationbar

I want to hide the rightNavigationBarItem when my ViewController loads. How is it possible? I have tried this code but it is not working.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: Where are the other places you are setting the `rightBarButtonItem`? Probably it is added again by the time view shows up.

Comment: actually i have created a class of tabbar that inherits from uitabbarcontroller.in that class itself i have added the right bar button item.but i have set the rightbarbutton for only one class but when i run my program,the rightbarbutton gets set for all other class as well.thanks

Comment: Hmm.. So are you subclassing `UITabBarController` or `UITabBar`? And did you put the `TabBarController` in a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: i am subclassing UiTabbarcontroller .No i am not putting the tabbarcontroller in a navigationcontroller

Comment: Why is everyone questioning why he wants to do this? I had the exact same requirement. When working with other people/companies you don't always have control over the designs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xcode 4. using these won't work;

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem release];
```

I'm actually interested why you mention rightBarButtonItem? When you navigate, its the leftBarButtonItem that changes.

What Does Work;

1) `self.title =@"";` nulling the title of the screen, when the navigation controller pushes a detail view onto the stack, no back button is created.

2) replacing the `leftBarButtonItem` with something else changes the button, but doesn't solve your problem.

3) An alternative. Hide the navigation bar; `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Comment: @eSpecialized: This is incorrect. Also, he did ask about the right bar button and your assuming he doesn't know which button he wants to hide is...strange.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson - because when a view controller loads. There is no button left or right, unless its part of a navigation stack.  The question suggests that he is having issues with the Left button. Perhaps an edit to the original question should be inquired. I read the question as a Navigation Stack push, which would mean left button.

Answer (score 5):

Hi it does not hide but make it disable

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

put this function in all the classes -

```
  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    }    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shouldn't be subclassing UITabBarController as stated quite clearly in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's mentioned very early in the overview.

Assuming that one of tabs points to a `UINavigationController`. You should really access the view controller directly and do something like `viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;`.

Answer (score 1):

You should set rightBarButtonItem to nil before you insert your controller into a navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

Directly hide right button is not working
Below is trick for do it.

Note: This solution work for iOS 7.x only.

```
//To Hide 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"";

//To Show
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"DONE";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is by this sample line code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```